# Android JNI bridge Toast C++ not working - How to fix it?

Tags: c++, delphi, java-native-interface, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I'm trying to solve a little problem with my hpp unit.
I found some examples on the internet showing how to Toast an information on screen with an Android JNI bridge, but it was just in pascal (delphi), so I decided to use the same pas file but with it an hpp file for conversion.
Till now I got it:

```
#ifndef Android_Jni_ToastHPP
#define Android_Jni_ToastHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-                                        // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx                                        // Zero-length empty class member 
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <FMX.Helpers.Android.hpp>                        // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNIBridge.hpp>                       // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp>                   // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp>     // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Util.hpp>                        // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNI.App.hpp>                         // Pascal unit
#include <FMX.Surfaces.hpp>                               // Pascal unit

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Android
{
namespace Jni
{
namespace Toast
{
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------

extern DELPHI_PACKAGE Androidapi::Jni::Toast __fastcall Toast(const System::UnicodeString Msg, TToastLength duration);

#pragma pack(pop)

//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------

}   /* namespace Android */
}   /* namespace JNI     */
}   /* namespace Toast   */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROID_JNI_TOAST)
using namespace Android::Jni::Toast;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROID_JNI)
using namespace Android::Jni;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROID)
using namespace Android;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // Androidapi_Jni_ToastHPP
```

If you would like to have the pascal unit, here is it:

```
unit Android.JNI.Toast;

interface

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}

type
  TToastLength = (LongToast, ShortToast);

  JToast = interface;

  JToastClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{69E2D233-B9D3-4F3E-B882-474C8E1D50E9}']
    { Property methods }
    function _GetLENGTH_LONG: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetLENGTH_SHORT: Integer; cdecl;
    { Methods }
    function init(context: JContext): JToast; cdecl; overload;
    function makeText(context: JContext; text: JCharSequence; duration: Integer)
      : JToast; cdecl;
    { Properties }
    property LENGTH_LONG: Integer read _GetLENGTH_LONG;
    property LENGTH_SHORT: Integer read _GetLENGTH_SHORT;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/widget/Toast')]
  JToast = interface(JObject)
    ['{FD81CC32-BFBC-4838-8893-9DD01DE47B00}']
    { Methods }
    procedure cancel; cdecl;
    function getDuration: Integer; cdecl;
    function getGravity: Integer; cdecl;
    function getHorizontalMargin: Single; cdecl;
    function getVerticalMargin: Single; cdecl;
    function getView: JView; cdecl;
    function getXOffset: Integer; cdecl;
    function getYOffset: Integer; cdecl;
    procedure setDuration(value: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure setGravity(gravity, xOffset, yOffset: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure setMargin(horizontalMargin, verticalMargin: Single); cdecl;
    procedure setText(s: JCharSequence); cdecl;
    procedure setView(view: JView); cdecl;
    procedure show; cdecl;
  end;

  TJToast = class(TJavaGenericImport<JToastClass, JToast>)
  end;

procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength = ShortToast);

{$ENDIF}

implementation

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength);
var
  ToastLength: Integer;
begin
  if duration = ShortToast then
    ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_SHORT
  else
    ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_LONG;
  CallInUiThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TJToast.JavaClass.makeText(SharedActivityContext, StrToJCharSequence(Msg),
        ToastLength).show
    end);
end;
{$ENDIF}

end.
```

However I get error when compilling using this source...
What con I do?

PS.: I arrived on that state just comparing AppMetthod sources with what I was making...

Log:

```
Checking project dependencies...
Compiling WebBrowser.cbproj (Debug, Android)
bccaarm command line for "uMain.cpp"
  c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\bin\bccaarm.exe -cc1 -D _DEBUG -isysroot 
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\platforms\android-14\arch-arm -idirafter =\usr\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -idirafter 
  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\PlatformSDKs\android-ndk-r9c\sources\android\native_app_glue -I 
  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Samples\CPP\Mobile Snippets\WebBrowser" -isystem "c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\include" -isystem "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\include\android\rtl" -isystem "c:\program files 
  (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\include\android\fmx" -isystem "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\include\android\crtl" -g 
  -fno-limit-debug-info -fborland-extensions -fborland-auto-refcount -nobuiltininc -nostdsysteminc -triple thumbv7-none-linux-androideabi -emit-obj 
  -mconstructor-aliases -pic-level 2 -target-abi aapcs-linux  -nostdinc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fexceptions -fcxx-exceptions -munwind-tables 
  -mstackrealign -fno-spell-checking -fno-use-cxa-atexit -main-file-name uMain.cpp -x c++ -std=c++11 -O0 -tU -o .\Android\Debug\uMain.o 
  -dependency-file .\Android\Debug\uMain.d -MT .\Android\Debug\uMain.o uMain.cpp 
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(36): expected a class or namespace
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(36): reference to 'Android' is ambiguous
  Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Android'
  FMX.Helpers.Android.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Fmx::Helpers::Android'
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(36): expected unqualified-id
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(47): expected a class or namespace
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(47): reference to 'Android' is ambiguous
  Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Android'
  FMX.Helpers.Android.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Fmx::Helpers::Android'
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(47): expected namespace name
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(50): expected a class or namespace
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(50): reference to 'Android' is ambiguous
  Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Android'
  FMX.Helpers.Android.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Fmx::Helpers::Android'
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(50): expected namespace name
[bccaarm Error] Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(53): reference to 'Android' is ambiguous
  Android.JNI.Toast.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Android'
  FMX.Helpers.Android.hpp(28): candidate found by name lookup is 'Fmx::Helpers::Android'
[bccaarm Error] uMain.cpp(32): use of undeclared identifier 'Toast'
Failed
Elapsed time: 00:00:05.8
```

EDIT:

New log file:

```
[bccaarm Error] Androidapi.JNI.Toast.hpp(36): no type named 'Toast' in namespace 'Androidapi::Jni'
[bccaarm Error] Androidapi.JNI.Toast.hpp(36): expected unqualified-id
[bccaarm Error] uMain.cpp(32): unexpected namespace name 'Toast': expected expression
Failed
```

Since now, thanks a lot.

Comment: `Androidapi::Jni::Toast` needs to be `void` in the return value of `Toast()`, and `TToastLength` is still not defined at all.  Stop manually editing your malformed .hpp file and let the IDE auto-generate a correct .hpp file for you.

Comment: How can I make the IDE make this work for me?

Comment: Add the .pas file to a C++ project, save the project, and then tell the IDE to compile the .pas file.  It will generate an .hpp file.  Or, you can invoke the command-line Delphi compiler (dcc32.exe) with the `/JPHNE` or `/JL` parameter to compile the .pas file directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .hpp file is malformed.

None of the public types defined in the `interface` section of the `.pas` file are defined in the `.hpp` file.  In particular, the `TToastLength` enum is missing.  And `Toast()` is declared as a `procedure` in the .pas file and thus has no return value, but it has an (erroneous) return value in the .hpp file.

Did you (or someone else) create the .hpp file manually?  I suspect this is the case, for two noticable reasons:

1. the `Android_JNI_ToastHPP` define in the initial `#ifndef`/`#define` does not match the `Fmx_Helpers_AndroidHPP` in the corresponding `#endif`.
2. the Delphi compiler always names C++ namespaces for Pascal unit names by uppercasing the first letter and lowercasing the remaining letters, but this .hpp file has an all-uppercase `JNI` namespace.

The Delphi compiler would not makes those mistakes.

With that said, `Android.JNI.Toast.pas` should be renamed to `Androidapi.JNI.Toast.pas` (and the .hpp file renamed and its namespaces updated accordingly) for consistency with Embarcadero's other JNI units (and to match the example in [this article](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE6AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm#Toast)).  That should also help alleviate the `reference to 'Android' is ambiguous` errors as well.

I strongly suggest you correct the .pas file, run it through the Delphi compiler once to produce the correct .hpp file, and then use it as-is in your C++ code.

Androidapi.JNI.Toast.pas:

```pascal
unit Androidapi.JNI.Toast;

interface

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;

type
  TToastLength = (LongToast, ShortToast);

  JToast = interface;

  JToastClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{69E2D233-B9D3-4F3E-B882-474C8E1D50E9}']
    { Property methods }
    function _GetLENGTH_LONG: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetLENGTH_SHORT: Integer; cdecl;
    { Methods }
    function init(context: JContext): JToast; cdecl; overload;
    function makeText(context: JContext; text: JCharSequence; duration: Integer)
      : JToast; cdecl;
    { Properties }
    property LENGTH_LONG: Integer read _GetLENGTH_LONG;
    property LENGTH_SHORT: Integer read _GetLENGTH_SHORT;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/widget/Toast')]
  JToast = interface(JObject)
    ['{FD81CC32-BFBC-4838-8893-9DD01DE47B00}']
    { Methods }
    procedure cancel; cdecl;
    function getDuration: Integer; cdecl;
    function getGravity: Integer; cdecl;
    function getHorizontalMargin: Single; cdecl;
    function getVerticalMargin: Single; cdecl;
    function getView: JView; cdecl;
    function getXOffset: Integer; cdecl;
    function getYOffset: Integer; cdecl;
    procedure setDuration(value: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure setGravity(gravity, xOffset, yOffset: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure setMargin(horizontalMargin, verticalMargin: Single); cdecl;
    procedure setText(s: JCharSequence); cdecl;
    procedure setView(view: JView); cdecl;
    procedure show; cdecl;
  end;

  TJToast = class(TJavaGenericImport<JToastClass, JToast>)
  end;

procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength = ShortToast);

{$ENDIF}

implementation

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.Helpers;

procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength);
var
  ToastLength: Integer;
begin
  if duration = ShortToast then
    ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_SHORT
  else
    ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_LONG;
  CallInUiThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TJToast.JavaClass.makeText(SharedActivityContext, StrToJCharSequence(Msg),
        ToastLength).show
    end);
end;
{$ENDIF}

end.
```

Androidapi.JNI.Toast.hpp:

```cpp
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2014 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'Androidapi.JNI.Toast.pas' rev: 28.00 (Android)

#ifndef Androidapi_Jni_ToastHPP
#define Androidapi_Jni_ToastHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member 
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>   // Pascal unit
#include <SysInit.hpp>  // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNIBridge.hpp> // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp> // Pascal unit
#include <Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp>   // Pascal unit
#include <System.Rtti.hpp>  // Pascal unit

//-- user supplied -----------------------------------------------------------

namespace Androidapi
{
namespace Jni
{
namespace Toast
{
//-- type declarations -------------------------------------------------------
enum DECLSPEC_DENUM TToastLength : unsigned char { LongToast, ShortToast };

__interface JToastClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JToastClass> _di_JToastClass;
__interface JToast;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JToast> _di_JToast;
__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{69E2D233-B9D3-4F3E-B882-474C8E1D50E9}") JToastClass  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObjectClass 
{

public:
    virtual int __cdecl _GetLENGTH_LONG(void) = 0 ;
    virtual int __cdecl _GetLENGTH_SHORT(void) = 0 ;
    HIDESBASE virtual _di_JToast __cdecl init(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JContext context) = 0 /* overload */;
    virtual _di_JToast __cdecl makeText(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JContext context, Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::_di_JCharSequence text, int duration) = 0 ;
    __property int LENGTH_LONG = {read=_GetLENGTH_LONG};
    __property int LENGTH_SHORT = {read=_GetLENGTH_SHORT};
};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{FD81CC32-BFBC-4838-8893-9DD01DE47B00}") JToast  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObject 
{

public:
    virtual void __cdecl cancel(void) = 0 ;
    virtual int __cdecl getDuration(void) = 0 ;
    virtual int __cdecl getGravity(void) = 0 ;
    virtual float __cdecl getHorizontalMargin(void) = 0 ;
    virtual float __cdecl getVerticalMargin(void) = 0 ;
    virtual Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JView __cdecl getView(void) = 0 ;
    virtual int __cdecl getXOffset(void) = 0 ;
    virtual int __cdecl getYOffset(void) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl setDuration(int value) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl setGravity(int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl setMargin(float horizontalMargin, float verticalMargin) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl setText(Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::_di_JCharSequence s) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl setView(Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JView view) = 0 ;
    virtual void __cdecl show(void) = 0 ;
};

class DELPHICLASS TJToast;
#pragma pack(push,4)
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJToast : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JToastClass,_di_JToast> 
{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JToastClass,_di_JToast>  inherited;

public:
    /* TJavaImport.Create */ inline __fastcall TJToast(void * ID, void * ClsID, Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaVTable* VTable) : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JToastClass,_di_JToast> (ID, ClsID, VTable) { }
    /* TJavaImport.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TJToast(void) { }

};

#pragma pack(pop)

//-- var, const, procedure ---------------------------------------------------
extern DELPHI_PACKAGE void __fastcall Toast(const System::UnicodeString Msg, TToastLength duration = (TToastLength)(0x1));
}   /* namespace Toast */
}   /* namespace Jni */
}   /* namespace Androidapi */
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROIDAPI_JNI_TOAST)
using namespace Androidapi::Jni::Toast;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROIDAPI_JNI)
using namespace Androidapi::Jni;
#endif
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROIDAPI)
using namespace Androidapi;
#endif
#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
//-- end unit ----------------------------------------------------------------
#endif  // Androidapi_Jni_ToastHPP
```

Comment: I made some modifications in that file and I had less errors than before...
I added 'void' before '__fastcall Toast ...'  so, it says that it doesn't returns any value.
About the two points you said, it was beacuse I had got some files from program files\Embarcadero\Studio\15\includes\android\rtl and copied some itens I thought was needed to mat it work... 
After add 'void' and rename JNIs namespaces to 'Jni' I had just three erros now, could you help me with that?

Comment: I have added the exact code that XE7's Delphi compiler auto-generates for the .hpp file.  It compiles fine for me in C++.

Comment: Thanks A LOT!
How did you converted it from .pas to .cpp? Is it automactic or manually as I was doing?
Another question related to this one. I cannot call a delphi package directly from .hpp source file as I was doing? I'm asking it because I saw Androidapi.IOUtils.hpp file as an example before start making this one, so it just call an pascal extern.

Comment: Like I said, the IDE can do it for you. Add the .pas file to a C++ project, save the project, and then tell the IDE to compile the .pas file. It will generate an .hpp file.  And yes, C++ code can call into a Delphi package.  That is why the Delphi compiler can generate .hpp files in the first place, to make those calls possible.

Comment: Hello, It's me again. I'm facing some problems when using this autogenerated file in C++ Builder Seattle (AppMethod). Now I'm unable to use .pas files in my application. So, when I include the <Androidapi.JNI.Toast.hpp> I just can't link it to my applicaiton to the funcions of the header. Should I open another topic or could it be discussed in here?

Comment: @mauroaraujo: it belongs in a new question. But in any case, the Starter and Pro editions of AppMethod do not support `.pas` files. You can't use the generated `.hpp` by itself, you need a `.pas`/`.dcu`/`.bpl` to provide the implementation for it to link to. On the other hand, generated `.hpp` files are version specific, you need to compile the `.pas` file in Seattle to use the `.hpp` file in Seattle. You could buy a license for a higher edition of AppMethod that supports `.pas` files, or else you should switch to RAD Studio with C++ and Delphi installed...

Comment: @mauroaraujo: ... which BTW is what you will likely have to do anyway considering that [Appmethod is being merged back into RAD Studio](http://community.embarcadero.com/article/news/16209-appmethod-merges-with-rad-studio-product-line)

Comment: Ok, but seems I've found the implementation under Androidapi.JNI.Widget.hpp. However I can't implement to it:

`void Toast(const String Msg){
 _di_JToast toast;
 _di_JContext context;
 toast = new Androidapi::Jni::Widget::JToastClass::makeText(context->getApplicationContext(), StrToJCharSequence(Msg), JToastClass::LENGTH_SHORT);
 toast->show();
}`

I get : _[bccaarm Error] Principal.cpp(2442): no type named 'makeText' in 'Androidapi::Jni::Widget::JToastClass'_

Comment: And if I try without "new" it says I'm trying to _[bccaarm Error] Principal.cpp(2442): call to non-static member function without an object argument_
And about AppMethod I'm really sad... Their licence are really expansive, mainly for poor students, the free edition was great.

Comment: Try this instead: `void Toast(const String &Msg) { _di_JToast toast = TJToast::JavaClass->makeText(TAndroidHelper::Context, TAndroidHelper::StrToJCharSequence(Msg), TJToast::JavaClass->LENGTH_SHORT); toast->show(); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99266/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-mauroaraujo).