# C++ Builder: Include JAR files

Tags: android, c++, jar, c++builder

I'm developping a Mobile Application using C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin Enterprise. The goal of the application is to scan barcodes, I use a Android PDA with a Barcode Scanner. The functions relative to the scanner are contained in a JAR file.

How can I use these functions in my project?

**EDIT**

I already add the Jar to my Project but I don't know what I have to include to use scanning functions.

**EDIT 2**

I created a Bridge File with Java2OP. According to the Embarcadero Documentation I have to translate it manually to C++ but I don't understand Delphi. Here is the code:

```
unit Android.JNI.ATLib;

interface

uses
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
// ===== Forward declarations =====

  JATLib = interface;//com.atid.lib.ATLib

// ===== Interface declarations =====

  JATLibClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{E264906A-B076-4960-9EAE-17DF2D2AEE74}']
    {class} function _GetINTERNAL_PATH: JString;
    {class} procedure _SetINTERNAL_PATH(Value: JString);
    {class} property INTERNAL_PATH: JString read _GetINTERNAL_PATH write _SetINTERNAL_PATH;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/atid/lib/ATLib')]
  JATLib = interface(JObject)
    ['{EFCFE579-FB94-432F-8DBB-851521F1EED7}']
  end;
  TJATLib = class(TJavaGenericImport<JATLibClass, JATLib>) end;

implementation

procedure RegisterTypes;
begin
  TRegTypes.RegisterType('Android.JNI.ATLib.JATLib', TypeInfo(Android.JNI.ATLib.JATLib));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTypes;
end.
```

Can you give me some advices to translate it to C++?

I also tried to include the pas file but when I compiled the project I have this error:

```
Compiler for "Delphi.Personality" and the platform "Android" is missing or unavailable.
```

**EDIT 3**

I succeeded to translate my bridge files to C++ thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016209/android-jni-bridge-toast-c-not-working-how-to-fix-it). I tried to use the function in my application like this:

```
TJATScanLib* scan = new TJATScanLib();
_di_JATScanLib scanner = scan->JavaClass->init();
```

There is no problem during the compilation but at the link step I have these errors:

"[ldandroid Erreur] C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-9c_x86_GIB.Build.22858.6822\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: .\Android\Debug\Connexion.o: in function TForm_Connexion::TForm_Connexion(System::Classes::TComponent*):C:\Users\dylan\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projets\PDA_Android/Connexion.cpp:28:error:

undefined reference to 'Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2, System::DelphiInterface >::GetJavaClass()'"

and " [ldandroid Erreur] C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-9c_x86_GIB.Build.22858.6822\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: .\Android\Debug\Connexion.o: in function TForm_Connexion::TForm_Connexion(System::Classes::TComponent*):C:\Users\dylan\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projets\PDA_Android/Connexion.cpp:30:error:

undefined reference to 'vtable for Android::Jni::Atscanlib::TJATScanLib'"

My bridge file:

```
#ifndef Android_JNI_ATScanLibH
#define Android_JNI_ATScanLibH

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member
#pragma pack(push,8)

#include <Androidapi.JNIBridge.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp>

#include <System.hpp>
#include <SysInit.hpp>

namespace Android{
namespace Jni{
namespace Atscanlib{

__interface JAsyncTask;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JAsyncTask> _di_JAsyncTask;

__interface JAsyncTaskClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JAsyncTaskClass> _di_JAsyncTaskClass;

__interface JAsyncTask_Status;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JAsyncTask_Status> _di_JAsyncTask_Status;

__interface JAsyncTask_StatusClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JAsyncTask_StatusClass> _di_JAsyncTask_StatusClass;

__interface JATScanLib;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JATScanLib> _di_JATScanLib;

__interface JATScanLibClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JATScanLibClass> _di_JATScanLibClass;

__interface JATScanLib_OnResponseListener;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JATScanLib_OnResponseListener> _di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListener;

__interface JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass> _di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass;

__interface JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask> _di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask;

__interface JATScanLib_TagSequenceTaskClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask> _di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTaskClass;

__interface JVoid;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JVoid> _di_JVoid;

__interface JVoidClass;
typedef System::DelphiInterface<JVoid> _di_JVoidClass;

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{73C141D6-F8D7-4FE4-BFA3-3441B6367189}") JAsyncTaskClass  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObjectClass
{
public:
    virtual JExecutor _GetSERIAL_EXECUTOR() = 0;
    virtual JExecutor _GetTHREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR() = 0;
    HIDESBASE virtual _di_JAsyncTask __cdecl init() = 0;
    HIDESBASE virtual void __cdecl execute(JRunnable runnable) = 0;

    __property JExecutor SERIAL_EXECUTOR = {read = _GetSERIAL_EXECUTOR};
    __property JExecutor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = {read = _GetTHREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR};

};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{73C141D6-F8D7-4FE4-BFA3-3441B6367189}") JAsyncTask  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObject
{
public:
    virtual bool __cdecl cancel(bool mayInterruptIfRunning) = 0;
    HIDESBASE virtual JObject __cdecl get() = 0;
    HIDESBASE virtual JObject __cdecl get(__int64 timeout, JTimeUnit unit_) = 0;
    virtual _di_JAsyncTask_Status __cdecl getStatus() = 0;
    virtual bool __cdecl isCancelled() = 0;

};
#pragma pack(push,4)

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJAsyncTask : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JAsyncTaskClass, _di_JAsyncTask>{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JAsyncTaskClass, _di_JAsyncTask> inherited;
    public:
        inline __fastcall TJAsyncTask() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JAsyncTaskClass, _di_JAsyncTask> (){}
        inline __fastcall virtual ~TJAsyncTask(void){}
};

#pragma pack(pop)


__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{16452E24-44D5-4E84-990E-3C1916FB372B}") JAsyncTask_StatusClass  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JEnumClass
{
public:
    virtual _di_JAsyncTask_Status _GetFINISHED() = 0;
    virtual _di_JAsyncTask_Status _GetPENDING() = 0;
    virtual _di_JAsyncTask_Status _GetRUNNING() = 0;
    virtual _di_JAsyncTask_Status __cdecl valueOf(JString name) = 0;
    virtual TJavaObjectArray__1<_di_JAsyncTask_Status> __cdecl values() = 0;


    __property _di_JAsyncTask_Status FINISHED = {read = _GetFINISHED};
    __property _di_JAsyncTask_Status PENDING = {read = _GetPENDING};
    __property _di_JAsyncTask_Status RUNNING = {read = _GetRUNNING};

};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{96B0BCE7-1312-49B9-9F33-43541680B0E7}") JAsyncTask_Status  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JEnum
{
};
#pragma pack(push,4)

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJAsyncTask_Status : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JAsyncTask_StatusClass, _di_JAsyncTask_Status>{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JAsyncTask_StatusClass, _di_JAsyncTask_Status> inherited;
    public:
        inline __fastcall TJAsyncTask_Status() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JAsyncTask_StatusClass, _di_JAsyncTask_Status> (){}
        inline __fastcall virtual ~TJAsyncTask_Status(void){}
};

#pragma pack(pop)

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{9A209D1D-07C6-4309-88AD-8A2EF359CF34}") JATScanLibClass  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObjectClass
{
public:
    virtual int _GetREAD_ENCODING_ERROR() = 0;
    virtual int _GetREAD_ERROR() = 0;
    virtual int _GetREAD_OK() = 0;
    virtual int _GetREAD_TIMEOUT() = 0;
    HIDESBASE virtual _di_JATScanLib __cdecl init() = 0;

    __property int READ_ENCODING_ERROR = {read = _GetREAD_ENCODING_ERROR};
    __property int READ_ERROR = {read = _GetREAD_ERROR};
    __property int READ_OK = {read = _GetREAD_OK};
    __property int READ_TIMEOUT = {read = _GetREAD_TIMEOUT};

};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{74B37E9E-F88A-4EB0-AEDF-538A472223A0}") JATScanLib  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObject
{
public:
    virtual int __cdecl Read(TJavaArray__1<Byte> P1) = 0;
    virtual JString __cdecl getReadResults() = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl init() = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl setEncoding(JString P1) = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl setOnResponseListener(_di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListener P1) = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl start() = 0;
    virtual void __cdecl stop() = 0;
};
#pragma pack(push,4)

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJATScanLib : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLibClass, _di_JATScanLib>{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLibClass, _di_JATScanLib> inherited;
    public:
        inline __fastcall TJATScanLib() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLibClass, _di_JATScanLib> (){}
        inline __fastcall virtual ~TJATScanLib(void){}
};

#pragma pack(pop)

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{654B87BA-B4EE-4102-85E9-9FDFF3C82BAA}") JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass  : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::IJavaClass
{
};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{35AC182B-7684-47EA-9BA8-07B504F85943}") JATScanLib_OnResponseListener  : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::IJavaInstance
{
public:
    virtual void __cdecl onResponse(int P1) = 0;
};
#pragma pack(push,4)

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJATScanLib_OnResponseListener : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass, _di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListener>{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass, _di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListener> inherited;
    public:
        inline __fastcall TJATScanLib_OnResponseListener() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListenerClass, _di_JATScanLib_OnResponseListener> (){}
        inline __fastcall virtual ~TJATScanLib_OnResponseListener(void){}
};

#pragma pack(pop)

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{1CF84DF6-6115-4FB5-9967-B55E74A3155C}") JATScanLib_TagSequenceTaskClass  : public _di_JAsyncTaskClass
{
};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{B83D8A9F-C1C4-4023-B1D8-3D9ABFB1FD2C}") JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask  : public _di_JAsyncTask
{
};
#pragma pack(push,4)

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJATScanLib_TagSequenceTask : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTaskClass, _di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask>{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTaskClass, _di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask> inherited;
    public:
        inline __fastcall TJATScanLib_TagSequenceTask() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTaskClass, _di_JATScanLib_TagSequenceTask> (){}
        inline __fastcall virtual ~TJATScanLib_TagSequenceTask(void){}
};

#pragma pack(pop)

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{E5AB6B2B-2580-469B-BBF6-C226984DFEBE}") JVoidClass : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObjectClass
{
public:
    virtual Jlang_Class _GetTYPE() = 0;
    __property Jlang_Class TYPE = {read = _GetTYPE};

};

__interface  INTERFACE_UUID("{013CC63A-938C-46BE-ACAC-BA854F2F6AC8}") JVoid  : public Androidapi::Jni::Javatypes::JObject
{
};
#pragma pack(push,4)

class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TJVoid : public Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JVoidClass, _di_JVoid>{
    typedef Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JVoidClass, _di_JVoid> inherited;
    public:
        inline __fastcall TJVoid() : Androidapi::Jnibridge::TJavaGenericImport__2<_di_JVoidClass, _di_JVoid> (){}
        inline __fastcall virtual ~TJVoid(void){}
};
#pragma pack(pop)
}
}
}
#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROID_JNI_ATLIB)
    using namespace Android::Jni::Atscanlib;
#endif

#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROID_JNI)
    using namespace Android::Jni;
#endif

#if !defined(DELPHIHEADER_NO_IMPLICIT_NAMESPACE_USE) && !defined(NO_USING_NAMESPACE_ANDROID)
    using namespace Android;
#endif

#pragma pack(pop)
#pragma option pop

#pragma delphiheader end.
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This topic is covered in Embarcadero's documentation:

[Using a Custom Set of Java Libraries In Your RAD Studio Android Apps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps)

> RAD Studio allows you to use your own or third-party Java libraries in RAD Studio applications.
>
> To use a custom set of libraries in your RAD Studio Android applications:
>
> 1. Ensure that your Java libraries meet the [RAD Studio requirements for Java libraries](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps#RAD_Studio_Requirements_for_Java_Libraries).
> 2. [Create a native bridge file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps#Creating_a_Native_Bridge_File_for_a_Java_Library) that your Delphi or C++ applications can use to access the APIs of your Java libraries.
> 3. [Add your Java libraries to your application](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_a_Custom_Set_of_Java_Libraries_In_Your_RAD_Studio_Android_Apps#Adding_Your_Java_Libraries_to_Your_Application).

What you are missing in your project is step #2. You can use Embarcadero's [Java2OP](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android) tool to generate that bridge file.

Comment: I know that I'm missing Step 2 but when I want to download Java2OP, it said that I don't have the good version. I need a XE and I have Berlin 10.1

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Java2OP is part of Berlin, you don't need an XE version. Simply login to your EDN account and download Java2OP for Berlin. You should have already registered your Berlin license beforehand.

Comment: Sorry! I thought that I have already registered my Berlin licence but I was still using the trial version. I downloaded Java2OP and I 'm about to create a bridge file. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: I have a problem to translate the Delphi bridge file to C++. When I include the .pas file in my project I have this error: "Compiler for "Delphi.Personality" and the platform "Android" is missing or unavailable". What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the project manager to do it.

1. In the **Project Manager**, extend the Target Platforms node of your project.
2. Within the Target Platforms node, extend the Android node.
   Right-click the Libraries node and select **Add**.
3. In the dialog box that opens, select the .jar file that you want to add to your application for Android, and select **Open**.

Comment: I already did that but I don't know which files to include to use the functions of the JAR file.

Comment: You'll need to add the JAR file itself into the Android node. After that, you must add the proper import into the code.

Comment: @JeanVitor the "proper import into the code" is what is missing. It is not enough to just add the JAR file itself, you also need code that USES the content of the JAR file. You *can* write that code manually, but it is tedious and error-prone to do so. Embarcadero has a Java2OP tool that generates that code for you.